# Android - How to change settings by code

Tags: android

in my application I would to change background and text colour (for example in Google Sky Map application you can set the "night mode" that changes background and text colour), how can I do the same thing using the same layout for both changes? I would to change also some text (for example I write Italian words and I would to change it in English words) if it's possible. Could some help me giving any tutorial, example or code? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically change text and background colors using specific methods on controls like:

```
View someView = findById(R.id.someView );
view.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.someDrawable );
```

But that would be one by one.  You can create a couple of styles, but unfortunately setting the style of a widget after it's been constructed is tedious because you'd have to make individual calls just like you did above:

```
View someView = findById(R.id.someView );
(TextView) view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
(TextView) view).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Finally there are Themes which are collections of Styles defined in resources that define all of your UI.  Themes can be set at once when an activity is created:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

[Choosing a style / theme programmatically at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861887/choose-style-at-run-time-programmatically)

As for text you can easily externalize your text using the strings.xml resource, and keep an italian version and english version, and Android will use the correct version that best corresponds with the user's locale settings.  There is a default strings.xml which will be used if Android can't find a matching strings resource for the user's locale.  Its usually a good idea to default to english for strings.xml, and create a strings_it.xml for italian.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: Yes I knew about strings.xml for different languages version but what I want to do is to change language with a pressure of a button. Is it possible to do that with    `SharedPreferences`    ? Also change background and text colour? How? Thank you.

Comment: My application has xml files in res/raw that work as data files. I would like to use another xml files in which there are other datas with some differences from the other xml file. The user must to decide which file want to use. I don't know if you know what I meant.