# How to get system defined all themes?

Tags: android, themes

> **Question:**- Does android provide any function to retrieve the all themes defined in the system.

Example: `Theme_Holo_Light` or others.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no

There are only two theme families for Android:

- Theme
- Theme.Holo

The later was introduced in Android 3.0 Honeycomb API 11, and you can knwo that in the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html)

> The standard system widgets and overall look have been redesigned and incorporate a new "holographic" user interface theme. The system applies the new theme using the standard style and theme system.
>   Any application that targets the Android 3.0 platform—by setting either the android:minSdkVersion or android:targetSdkVersion value to "11"—inherits the holographic theme by default.

These themes come with variants (basically: Light and Dark)

So when you design a theme:

- either you create everything from scratch
- either you inherit from the `Theme.DeviceDefault`, knowing that it will depends on the Android version of each device, hence you may create a variation of your theme in `values-v11` for Holo

Comment: Related blog post of interest: [Holo everywhere](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply ,your means that we can not get all themes provided by system or we do not have any function to retrieve that.

Comment: @Cobra Indeed. You can inderectly know it at runtime by [checking the version of Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093365/how-can-i-check-the-system-version-of-android). And you can [design for it thanks to `values-v11`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861887/choosing-a-style-theme-programmatically-at-run-time)